# How to make a line to go over image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to make a line to go over image, not to see the end in the left bottom corner. It has no problem when line is not this thick, but with this thickness, I have a problem. How I make line longer?

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
img = Image.new('RGB', (1000, 1000), (0,0,0)) 
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.line((1000, -250, 0, 750), (255,0,0), 350)
img
```

[image]

Comment: Do you understand why it looks like this? Can you think of a way you could change the end point of the line, in order to avoid the problem? (What would happen if you continued stroking this path towards the bottom-left?) Can you think of a mathematical rule that tells you what end point to use, in terms of the line thickness?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Now I understand that I don't need to use a line in order to get what I want. Thanks!

Comment: What? No, you should use a line. You should use it the way that is suggested in the answer you accepted. I was trying to get you to figure out how to do that, by yourself.

Comment: Yes, but when I read your comment I got an idea for a better solution. I accepted the answer, because it is what I asked and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the end of the line further towards the bottom left:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
img = Image.new('RGB', (1000, 1000), (0,0,0)) 
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.line((1000, -250, -500, 1250), (255,0,0), 350)
img.show()
input()
```

and the end of the line won't be visible anymore

Comment: Thanks. This solution is working, but I figured that I need to do this in another way.